# SAS Macro Variable Quoted Concatenation

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

I am debugging a macro I am writing that will treat a string as either a prefix or suffix of a dataset name based on user input.  Then, the quoted result will be fed into another process downstream.

So if the user says Type=1 and provides the string 'data_', the output of the resulting macro variable will be 'data_%'.

I've tried a few different iterations of the below code, but can't quite get it....any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
%let Type=1;
%let TableName=data_;

data _null_;
   if &Type=1 then 
      call symput('qTableName',%unquote(%str(%')(cats(&TableName.,"%"))%str(%')));
   else if &Type=2 then 
      call symput('qTableName',%unquote(%str(%')(cats("%",&TableName.))%str(%')));
run;

%put &qTableName;
```

Comment: Since you are using a data step why are you also using all of those macro functions? `call symputx('qtablename',cats(symget('TableName'),'_%'))`. Also are the single quotes part of the value in the generated macro variable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to add single quotes to a macro variable.

```
%let TableName=data_;
%let qTableName='data_%';
```

So in a data step you can use `CATQ()`.

```
data _null_;
   call symputx('qTableName',catq('1a',cats(symget('TableName'),'%')));
run;
```

Or in simple macro code just use `%bquote()` to allow you to add `'` and `%` without preventing macro variable expansion. But you probably want to remove the macro quoting it will cause.

```
%let qTableName=%unquote(%bquote('&TableName%'));
```

Or if you only want to add the `%` when &TYPE=1 then perhaps you could call the `IFC()` function.  I believe that the `%sysfunc()` call will remove the macro quoting.

```
%let Type=1;
%let qTableName=%sysfunc(ifc(&type=1,%bquote('&TableName%'),%bquote('&TableName')));
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  The solution you provided in the data step works perfectly for my needs.